# Accessing a certain column in the pandas index section

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this.

```
                                (0.0, 0.0)  (0.0, 0.1)  ...  (0.0, 1.0)  (1.0, 1.0)
time    fep-lambda coul-lambda                          ...                        
0.0     0.0        0.0           14.892123   18.579500  ...   51.766440   51.756029
0.2     0.0        0.0           14.894775   22.518230  ...   91.129579   91.520701
0.4     0.0        0.0           14.895931   19.451097  ...   60.447812   60.004942
0.6     0.0        0.0           14.878677   22.785883  ...   93.951005   93.925352
```

Where the columns go from (0.0, 0.0) to (1.0, 1.0) and the index section has three columns time, fep-lambda and coul-lambda. I could extract the time column via `[value[0] for value in df.index.values]` but I'm not quite sure if there is a more pythonic way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
df.index.get_level_values('time')
```

as per: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html#pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values